# Is there anyway to create dismissible tooltip on text form fields in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-animation

I am new to the flutter world and trying to create a form with real-time validation. Is there any way to create such a dismissible tooltip (see screenshot) for text form fields?

Note: Tooltip will be visible only when focus is on the text form field.

[image]

Comment: rather than seeing it as a tool tip, see it as a custom widget, a rounded container with a column as a children

Comment: In Flutter, you have control over every pixel. So, to answer your question: yes, there is.

Answer (score 0):

it gotta be some custom code.
put field into stack and draw tooltip above other elements, add flag if it is shown/hidden, on x button and focusscope changes toggle it, on field update get checker warnings